# Git repository not cloning

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, crm

I am trying to install fat free crm using these instructions http://guides.fatfreecrm.com/Setup-Linux-or-Mac-OS.html. But I am not able to run even the first instruction
This is what I get when I try to clone the repository

Cloning into 'fat_free_crm'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I suppose its an open software so I should be having permission and it obviously exists.
I have a fresh install of ubuntu with only git installed in it

Comment: Try cloning it using the http protocol: git clone https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are trying to download using the ssh link and you have not configured your ssh. Instead try this

```
git clone https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm.git
cd fat_free_crm
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your ssh key to your account?

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-4-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account

If you're not sure wether you have generated & associated a private key to SSH, you can check using:

$ssh-add -l